# Using Cloud Functions to filter data by string from cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, ajax, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to filter a firestore data by string, and knowing that firestore don't have a proper way to do this inside his tools (Something as "%LIKE%" SQL operator) our new strategy is to use cloud functions to filter this data using a regex and recover it after.
But we having some troubles:

1-Can we manage assync functions inside Cloud Functions?

2-After this function, how can we recover this data? (We trying to use Fetch(),but looks like it don't works.)

Here's my Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin     = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(MY CREDENTIALS)

exports.filterAdverts = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {
  let vm = this;
  let filteredResults = [];
  let {filter,id_client} = JSON.parse(req.body);
  let regex = new RegExp(filtro, 'i');

 admin
.firestore()
.collection('database')
.doc(id_client)
.collection('classifieds')
.where('active', '==', 1)
.get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.data().txt_comentary.match(regex)) {
          filteredResults.push(doc.data())
        }
      })
    });
  res.send(filteredResults.toString())
});
```

As you can see, i need to filter the variable txt_comentary by the Regex. Here's the fetch function:

```
    filterAds: function(){
      let filter = {filter:this.form_seach.filtro_comentary, id_cliente:this.id_cliente};
      fetch('Cloud-function-URL', {

        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors'
      }).then(async (response) => {
        await console.log(response)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

I'm really stucked to do this, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reach a result, i'm used the onCall function to trigger it. Here's the code from cloud function:

```
exports.filterAds = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
  let vm = this;
  let filteredResults = [];
  let {filter,id_client} = data;
  let regex = new RegExp(filter, 'i');
    await admin.firestore().collection('database').doc(id_client).collection('classifieds').where('active', '==', 1) .get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.data().txt_comentary.match(regex)) {
          filteredResults.push(doc.data())
        }
      })
    })
    return filteredResults;

});
```

and here's the function to trigger it:

```
    filter_Ads: function () {
      const vm = this;
      const filteredValues = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("filtrarAnuncios");


      valoresFiltrados({
        filter: *input string*,
        id_cliente: *part of path in my firebase search*,
      })
        .then(async (response) => {
          console.log(respose)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

With this i can filter by the regex and recover the result from this cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify the version of nodejs and use a modern one that handle `async / await`.

you should call `res.send` inside your `.then(snapshot => {...})` not after, because here you are calling it before getting the data from the database

Also in your test, instead of `await console.log(response)` you should do `console.log(await response.text())`

A few other things are surprising with your code, like how you just `.toString` your array instead of sending it as `JSON`

Comment: I'm still a begineer, thank you for the help!
I'm still having some troubles with ajax fetch(). I have this log "TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body." You know how to handle this error?

Comment: No problem, keep it up, this is an error you can probably understand with a bit of search, if you want your request to contain a body, you should use the http method `POST` instead of the default `GET`.

Google it for a more complete answer :)